# Sequelize automatically save association objects when parent is saved

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Given the following model:

```
var Project = sequelize.define('project', {/* ... */})
var Task = sequelize.define('task', {/* ... */})

Project.hasMany(Task, {as: 'Tasks'});
Task.belongsTo(Project);
```

How can make changes to tasks and have the database updated when I save the project.

```
Project.findById(1, {include: Task, as: 'tasks'}).then(function(project) {
  project.tasks.each(function(task) {
    task.status = 'done';
  });
  project.status = 'closed';
  project.updatedBy = 'user';
  // ...many more statements that modify the project and tasks for example
  project.save(); // << I want this to save the whole hierarchy to the database, similar to how Hibernate does it, if some people are familiar
});
```

When `project.save()` is called, the tasks are not updated. Why?

Comment: Why don't you just call `tasks[0].save();`  ?

Comment: @aray12 perhaps my example was too simplistic, I've updated the code a little, also imagine the project has many other relationships that I will modify. There must be a away to call `.save()` or some other method on the single parent object and have the whole hierarchy saved to the database

Answer (score 1):

If you use `find` or `findAll` you can take advantage of eager-loading as described in [Eager loading](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#eager-loading).

To do this, you need to use the attribute `include` like: `include: [Task]`

This way you have an inner join and don't need to query for the tasks.

Based on your code above, you can have:
(I can't test this code right now, sorry if it's not working perfectly):

```
Project.find({ where: {id: 1}, include: [{model: Task, as: 'task'}]})
    .then(function(project) {      
        project.task[0].updateAttributes({
            status = 'done';
        }).then(function() {
            //done!
        });
    });
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22593767/2056394) may be helpful too.