# Working example for updating associative table data with Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

This is my model:

```js
var Vote = sequelize.define('vote', {
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
    }
});

var Choice = sequelize.define('choice', {
    choiceTitle: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    count: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        length: 6
    }
});
Choice.belongsTo(Vote);
Vote.hasMany(Choice, {onUpdate: 'cascade'});
```

Below is the code to update the 'votes' table including associated 'choices' table if possible using 'vote' argument of 'store()' which is already an object of a Vote with updated values including 'choices' from the app.

```js
store(vote, callback) {
    return Vote.findById(vote.id, {
        include: [
            {
                model: Choice,
                as: 'choices'
            }
        ]
    }).then(function(resVote) {
        resVote.choices[0].updateAttributes({count: 120}) // just to test if at least it gets written to db
            .then(function(res) {
                callback(null, res);
            }).catch((err) => callback(err, null));
    });
},
```

FYI: In the code I just set one attribute of a specific choice to 120, just to see if it gets written down in the postgres-db, and, hooray, that works (thanks to Jan Aagaard's reply on [Updating attributes in associated models using Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586712/updating-attributes-in-associated-models-using-sequelize) to at least have an update on associated table).

I did not really find a solution in Sequelize's docs (at least they have some). When I try to 'save()', 'update()' or 'upsert()' vote directly it just creates a completely new row with empty fields if null is allowed, or simply fails if null is disallowed.

What is the recommended way to update all (changed) fields of a table and if possible also an associated table in Sequelize? Sorry if this question is a bit basic, but I'm quite stuck right now and did not find a clear answer for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an `include` obj to creates (see under "Creating with associations" on http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/associations/) but it doesn't look like you can do so with updates.

I think what you want to do is fetch the related record(s) using the relationship accessors Sequelize gives you and update those instances:

```
 Vote.findById(vote.id)
  .then(function(vote) {
    return vote.getChoices()
  })
  .then(function(choices) {
    return choices[0].update({ count: 120 })
  })
  .then(function(choice) {
    callback(null, choice);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    callback(err);
  });

  (I realise this means you lose the join and end up with two separate queries, but I can't think another way of doing this just now)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. This pointed me to the right direction, I still have troubles to get the right choice out of the vote object, but at least a step further now. I'll keep this updated, if I ever have a working example.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to post a new question for that separate issue if you need to

Comment: I leave it as is, because I use now MongoDB as backend, it's just much easier to get documents with nested elements into the db, I just needed the ORM to use postgres, because it's free on Heroku. But I found out there is a mongoDB provision on it for free too ;-)